# Is this sentence okay to wish Mother's Day?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

I'm going to make a design and I'm writing a copy on it which will be:

On this Mother's day, let's thank her for **(her?)** selfless care **(for us?)**.

(Not very sure if **care** and **care for** has different meanings. Would like to know if there's any difference)

Now first doubt is about grammar. That's why I've put optional parts in brackets. Secondly her seems a bit redundant to me. So I'm not sure if it is grammatically okay or not.

Another doubt is: Is this sentence okay to show my feelings for my mother? Basically I want to show that my mother has cared **(for?)** me the most in my life. By care I mean:

She asks me how are you, have you eaten your food, please let me know whenever you feel sick, don't do this, don't do that because it's bad, take rest you're tired, here's your favorite food and so many other things. I hope you got idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been asked on English Language & Usage

Comment: Cross-posted to EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/533735/116151